# Django: Filtering Many To Many, Find an Instance where multiple connected model instances exist

Tags: python, django

I have the following model where a thread can have many people. I would like to find a thread which contains specific users if it exists.

```
class Thread(models.Model):

    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through="UserThread")

class UserThread(models.Model):

    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Message(models.Model):

    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name="messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="sent_messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

What I would like is to check if there is a `thread` which has 2 of the following users (`user1` and `user2`):

`thread = Thread.objects.get(Q(UserThread__user==user1) & Q(UserThread__user==user2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return all the threads with 2 of the following users:

```
 Thread.objects.filter(Q(userthread__user=user1), Q(userthread__user=user2))
```

And if you want to check if there are any threads with 2 of the following users you can do it with [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists).

```
 Thread.objects.filter(Q(userthread__user=user1), Q(userthread__user=user2)).exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

for complex queryset I suggest you use `filter` queryset instead of get because filter will return zero or more results but get must return exactly one result and by any chance if you have multiple entries you need to handle `MultipleObjectsReturned` and `DoesNotExist` if no result found

```
Thread.objects.filter(Q(userthread__user=user1) & Q(userthread__user=user2))
```

Note: I have used `userthread` instead of `UserThread` because table in your database will be created by name `userthread`

Comment: This doesn't work, because Django doesn't run with error: Keyword Argument repeated.

Comment: check updated answer.. there won't be any table with name UserThread in database because when you run migrations table name store in lower case only and to execute queryset you need to use table name as in database